# How to style my required form fields?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form on my page and using the jQuery validation plugin from http://jqueryvalidation.org
it displays errors under the form fields if they are not supplied.

What I'm wondering is how I can style these errors? I basically want the error to show inside the actual field itself and the text to be a certain color. How can I do this?

Here is my webpage
http://geofilterme.com/makemeone/

```
<form id="form" class="topBefore" method="post" action="thankyou.php">
      <input id="name" type="text" name="sender" placeholder="Name" required="">
          <input id="email" type="email" name="senderEmail" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
      <input id="snapchat" type="text" name="snapchat" placeholder="Snapchat username">
      <input id="reach" type="text" name="reach" placeholder="Estimated reach (number of people)" required="">
          <textarea id="message" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Describe what you want on the geofilter, and what it&#8217s for:" required=""></textarea>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

Comment: style with css. position will be in the jquery

Comment: I'm not sure where to find the position. And what do I call in the CSS?

Comment: Each of your elements has an id. These will allow you to style them individually. For example: `#name { width: 100px; }`. If you wish to style multiple elements, use the same class name on each element: `class="form_input_fields"` and then css to style all of them: `.form_input_fields { width: 100px; }`

Comment: I'm not trying to style the fields, I'm trying to style the "this field is required" messeges that appear from the jQuery plugin

Comment: i see all the answers in the plugin's site, please dont ask to you have do some basic work first.

Comment: Also, why would you tag `php` if your question has nothing to do with it at all?

Comment: I really can't find the answers on the site. Could you direct me to the relevant part?

Answer (score 0):

First you must have searched the javascript validate file, inside in some line of code it tells you what class to use for all the error elements and creates a specific id for each element that uses validation with the id that you give.

E.g.
if you have given your element an id of 'email' it will take that and create a label element that hold the error with an id of 'email-error'.

The piece of code that does that in jquery.validate.js is this

```
// Create error element
error = $( "<" + this.settings.errorElement + ">" )
    .attr( "id", elementID + "-error" )
    .addClass( this.settings.errorClass )
    .html( message || "" );
```

So in your case the individual id's and class for errors is:

ID:
email-error, reach-error, message-error

Class:
error

Or you can just look with some tools that can help you such as firebug, browser developer tools e.t.c.

Before you ask plase first search a little bit more of yourself.

Comment: Thanks but I can't figure out how to add the error message inside the actual field? I want it to come after the labels, "Name", "Email" etc

Comment: There is a ton of options in the jquery.validate documentation to try and do that. We give you the first steps. Just search. Don't expect to give the answer to your hands if you have not tried something first.